# How to delete row with just one column duplicated in sql?

Tags: sql

This is my records.

[image]

I just want to delete records with

PACK = '1`S'

but if the row does not have any duplicates even if its PACK is equals to '1`S' it will remain.

[image]

The only thing I can do is to check the records that have duplicates.
And to delete records with PACK = 1's.

`SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as duplicates
FROM table1
Group by Name
having COUNT(*) >1
Order by duplicates`

Note: I just replace delete with select.

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE PACK = '1's'`

Comment: which database??

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images, or links to images.

Comment: what's your effort?

Comment: You are supposed to come here with a concrete problem you are facing. Your question "How to delete row ..." can be answered with "Use UPDATE". You probably know this. So where are you actually stuck? What have you tried? Why didn't it work for you?

Comment: if its only small amount of data you could create a new table insert the distinct rows from the old table, rename the old table then rename the new table, if it all looks good then drop the old table

Comment: @dbajtr Hi Sir, my table has a thousands of records.

Comment: @EugeneSantos thats not too bad- try it on a test database should be be able to script it and do the whole thing in less that 30 seconds

Comment: You still haven't told us which DBMS you are using. You should always tag the DBMS when asking SQL questions, as the SQL dialect difffer.

Comment: On a sidenote: You table is not normalized. It seems you would need a table product that tells us product name and category and another table product_pack, specifying size and price for a product in order to avoid redundancy and possible inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to delete any 1`S records for which **exists** a record with the same name and category and another pack. You can word exactly this in SQL:

```
delete from table1
where pack = '1`S' 
and exists
(
  select *
  from table1 other
  where other.name     =  table1.name
    and other.category =  table1.category
    and other.pack     <> table1.pack
);
```

This is standard SQL and should work in about every DBMS. With MySQL being the notorious exception, as they forbid to directly use the updated table in a subquery again. Here you'd have to replace `from table1 other` by `from (select * from table1) other`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this pl/sql can guide you:

```
Delete from table1
    where id not in (select min(id) 
                         from table1
                         where pack = '1`S'
                         group by name
                         having count(*) = 1
                    )
          and pack = '1`S';
```

Comment: it would be the same for t-sql too

Comment: This is not PL/SQL. PL/SQL is Oracle's programming language built into the DBMS. What you are showing is SQL.

Comment: "PL/SQL is a combination of SQL along with the procedural features of programming languages." I wanted to emphasise, this is a syntax for Oracle DBMS's.

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN the table on itself with the restriction that the ID field is larger than the ID field found by the join. If there are no duplicates there will not be any results. If there are duplicates the most recently added will be deleted.